# Python 3.4.3 - Sorting statistical list alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.4

I have a text file that shows a list of example names, followed by their score earned an arithmetic test.

```
Aaa = 10
Ccc = 9
Ddd = 1
Bbb = 5
```

In another script, I need to be able to select an option to sort the list alphabetically, and sustain this after more names are added to the list, like this:

```
Aaa = 10
Bbb = 5
Ccc = 9
Ddd = 1
```

This way, the names are listed alphabetically and are adjacent to their original scores. I have tried the `sort` function,

```
 f=open('score.txt','r')
 readfile=str(f.readlines())
 readfile.rstrip('\n')
 print(sorted(readfile))
```

However this only sorts each character of the file and returns this:

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", ',', ',', ',', '0', '1', '1', '5', '9', '=', '=', '=', '=', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '[', '\\', '\\', '\\', '\\', ']', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n']
```

Comment: Why did you convert the list of lines read to a string? Remove your `str()` call. You want to leave in the newlines if you want to write it out again; in any case your `readfile.rstrip()` call is useless because you a) ignore the result and b) there is no newline at the end of `readfile` because it ends in `]` instead.

Comment: Had you used `f.readlines()` alone, `sorted()` would have worked fine as you'd have had a list of strings to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a list, you have *one string*:

```
readfile=str(f.readlines())
```

This converted your list to a string, including the `[`, `]` start and end and the `,` commas between the original lines.

Don't do that, there is *absolutely no need* to convert a list of strings to a string here. Just sort the lines you read:

```
readfile = f.readlines()
print(sorted(readfile))
```

You don't even need to call `f.readlines()` here, as `sorted()` can take any iterable, including a file object:

```
with open('score.txt') as infile:
    readfile = sorted(infile)

print(readfile)
```

You'll need to take into account that if there are any names that are duplicated in the file, they will be sorted lexicographically according to the digits following the `=` character, not numerically. This means `100` is sorted before `9` because `1` comes before `9` in the Unicode standard.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I also used this `readfile = [w.replace('\n','') for w in readfile]` to eliminate \n from the output.

Comment: @HelpMeWithMyCode: then use `[w.rstrip('\n') for w in readfile]` to only remove them from the end (the only location you'll find the newlines anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a string representation of the list returned from readlines with `str(f.readlines())` so calling sorted on that is going to sort each character, just call sorted on the file object:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    print(sorted(f))
```

Output:

```
['Aaa = 10\n', 'Bbb = 5', 'Ccc = 9\n', 'Ddd = 1\n']
```

To remove the newlines use map:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = map(str.rstrip,sorted(f))
    print(lines)
```

Output:

```
['Aaa = 10', 'Bbb = 5', 'Ccc = 9', 'Ddd = 1']
```

Basically what is happening in your code:

```
In [4]: l = ["1","2","3","4"] # readlines list

In [5]: str(l) # you turn it into a str
Out[5]: '[1, 2, 3, 4]'

In [6]: sorted(str(l)) # calling sorted sorts the individual characters
Out[6]: [' ', ' ', ' ', ',', ',', ',', '1', '2', '3', '4', '[', ']']
```

Once you have a sorted file, to put the new name in the correct place you can use a tempfile to write to and replace the original file with shutil.move:

```
new_n, new_s = "Bar",12
from shutil import move
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
with open("in.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w",dir=".",delete=False) as t:
    for line in f:
        if line >= new_n:
            t.write("{} = {}\n".format(new_n, new_s))
            t.write(line)
            t.writelines(f)
            break
        t.write(line)
    else:
        t.write("{} = {}\n".format(new_n, new_s))
move(t.name,"in.txt")
```

After sorting originally and writing in.txt:

```
Aaa = 10
Bbb = 5
Ccc = 9
Ddd = 1
```

in.txt after running the code:

```
Aaa = 10
Bar = 12
Bbb = 5
Ccc = 9
Ddd = 1
```

If the next run we add "Foo":

```
Aaa = 10
Bar = 12
Bbb = 5
Ccc = 9
Ddd = 1
Foo = 12
```

The else is executed as we found no line/name greater than or equal to foo.

If you had a sorted list and you wanted to insert the new data into the list and maintain order you could use the bisect module:

```
new_n, new_s = "Bar",12
from bisect import insort

with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = sorted(f)
    insort(lines,"{} = {}".format(new_n, new_s))
    print(lines)
```

Output:

```
['Aaa = 10\n', 'Bar = 12\n', 'Bbb = 5\n', 'Ccc = 9\n', 'Ddd = 1\n']
```

Comment: you could strip out the white spaces

Comment: @VigneshKalai,  I think the OP just wants to sort the content originally and then keep it ordered when there are new names added